# How to compute difference between the values of thecolumns of two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: T_Guest, T_Table

In **T_Guest** I have a list of the guests. Each guest has an ID (**g_no**) and ID of a table (**t_no**) to which the guest is related.
It is possible that to the same table will be related many guests.

In the **T_Table** I have a list of the tables. Each table has an ID (**t_no**) and a field **n_places** that describes how many places that table does have.

QUESTION:
**I need to build an SQL query (in MS Access), which will show a list of a tables ID's which are still have a free sits.**

---

I have an idea to find first the list of the tables which are full, and than just to implement EXCEPTION on that group from the whole group of the available tables.

But to compute how many tables does have ZERO free places, I need somehow to compute for each table:

```
n_places - NUMBER_OF_GUESTS_ON_THAT_TABLE
```

Where the last one (`NUMBER_OF_GUESTS_ON_THAT_TABLE`) it's just:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T_Table INNER JOIN T_Guest ON T_Table.t_no = T_Guest.t_no
GROUP BY T_Table.t_no
```

But I don't how to implement DIFFERENCE **n_places - NUMBER_OF_GUESTS_ON_THAT_TABLE**

Can somebody help me with that kind of a task???

Answer (score 3):

You can use the guest count as a derived table:

```
SELECT t.t_no, t.n_Places-Nz(g.Guests,0) As FreePlaces
FROM T_Table t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t_no,COUNT(*) as Guests
    FROM T_Guest 
    GROUP BY t_no) g
ON t.t_no = g.t_no
```

To get tables with spaces, you can add:

```
WHERE t.n_Places-Nz(g.Guests,0)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [tt].[t_no]
FROM T_Table AS tt
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_Guest AS tg WHERE tg.t_no = tt.t_no) < tt.n_places
```

Should work in access, uses a subquery but given the context I don't think this will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is classic for the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT t_no FROM T_Guest GROUP BY t_no
HAVING COUNT(*)<(SELECT T_Table.n_Places FROM T_Table WHERE T_Table.t_no=T_Guest.t_no)
```

Comment: To tell a truth I can't understand the logic behind this query :( Could you explain it to me please? To be particular, I don't understand the meaning of:                                     `HAVING COUNT(*)<(SELECT n_Places FROM T_Table WHERE T_Table.t_no=T_Guest,t_no)`

Comment: You can't use WHERE on aggregate functions such as COUNT(). HAVING is an equivalent to WHERE for these cases.